# Android wear DataApi onDataChanged() not called for all requests

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to use `DataApi` and `DataApi.DataListener` to send data from phone to watches, but `onDataChanged` is not called for all requests (only some are delivered) send from phone `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request)` although `ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>()` result is successful for all requests

To be sure data are always different (onDataChanged() is called only when data has changed) I am adding time stamp to `DataMap` for each request like this: `myRequestDataMap.putLong("timeStamp", System.currentTimeMillis())` and to be called immediately using `setUrgent()`

For debug purposes I also send message using `MessageApi` right after request and all messages are delivered.

Notes:

- `applicationId` is same for both phone and watch apps
- `play-services-wearable` version is also same and 9.8.0
- `com.google.android.wearable:wearable` version is 2.0.3
- tested with LG G Watch and emulator

EDIT:
watch app manifest

```
<manifest
package="app.package"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="app.package.Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

EDIT 2:

Phone app:

```
public class App extends Application implements MessageApi.MessageListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    //as response to data request
    ...
    //load data from DB
    ...
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ...

        PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = myObject.generateDataMap();
        dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putLong("timeStamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PutDataRequest request = dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
        PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi
            .putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);

        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final DataApi.DataItemResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed");
                }
            }
        });

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

}
```

}

Wear app:

```
public class WearActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, DataApi.DataListener, NodeApi.NodeListener, 
    MessageApi.MessageListener {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    final List<DataEvent> events = FreezableUtils.freezeIterable(dataEvents);
    for (DataEvent event : events) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
            ...
        }
    }
}

 @Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Wearable.NodeApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Can anybody help?

Comment: You may want to check [SO post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268174/ondatachanged-is-never-called) and [SO post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420606/ondatachanged-not-being-called-on-android-wear). See if it will help you. Otherwise, I suggest that you also share what you've already done such as codes in main activity for both phone and wearable.

Comment: I've updated my question